# php-Help in comparing array with string entered

Tags: php

i am trying to the count the strings which i have stored in array to the name which the user enters by comparing them I am getting error my code is

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php 
    $wc=0;
    $m=array("kill","lop");
    $name = $_REQUEST['fname'];
    for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
    {
    if($m[i]==$name)
    $wc=$wc+1;
    }
    echo $wc; 
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>

    i am getting error undefined i reference please help
```

Comment: is that a typo inside `$m[i]` or is it `$i`

Answer (score 0):

Easier thing is

```
<?php 
        $wc=0;
        $m=array("kill","lop");
        $name = isset($_POST['fname'])?$_POST['fname']:'';
        if (in_array($name, $m))
        {
            $wc=$wc+1;
        }
        echo $wc; 
    ?>
```

Comment: if built-in function already available then why do you need to complicate the things

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if what user entered is in your array:

```
if (in_array($_REQUEST['fname'], $m)) {
   echo "found";
}
else {
  echo "not found";  
}
```

Alternative using for loop:

```
   for ($i=0, $c = count($m); $i<$c; ++$i) {
    if ($m[$i] == $_REQUEST['fname']) {
        echo "found";
        break;
    }
   }
```

Comment: You can use for loop as in alternative above

Answer (score 0):

You have error because in your if block `i` is not a variable need to be `$i` !

```
if($m[i]==$name)
```

Replace:

```
if($m[$i]==$name)
```

Comment: thank u can u explain that can in membership fn be used like python in for loop

Comment: You use `for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)` where you declare a variable `$i`, and then this variable you use in your `if` block. In your for cycle you can also use `count` for count element of array example - `for($i=0; $i<count($m); $i++) `